# Switching X and Y axis around on Google Line chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

On my X-axis is ip addresses (String) and my Y-Axis is percentages (Numbers), However I want to switch them around and when I try to do it on my code I get "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type" error. I think it's because it does not allow the first column to be a Number.

Switching addColumn/addRow statements around to start with numbers (memory usage and CPU Usage) and end with server IP.
Using arrayToDataTable instead of DataTable.

```
           /*<![CDATA[*/
            var serverStatuses = /*[[${serverStatuses}]]*/ 'default';
            /*]]>*/
            var performanceData =new google.visualization.DataTable();

            performanceData.addColumn('number', 'CPU Usage');
            performanceData.addColumn('number', 'Memory Usage');
            performanceData.addColumn('string', 'Server IP');

            for (var n = 0; n < serverStatuses.length; n++) {
                performanceData.addRow([serverStatuses[n].memoryUsage,
                    serverStatuses[n].cpuUsage, 
                 serverStatuses[n].ipAddress]);
            }
```

IP addresses on the Y-Axis and Percentages on the X-Axis.

Comment: @WhiteHat Here's my dto class, I retrieve a list List of the data from the database.

    public class ServerStatusParameters {
    private String totalPhysicalMemory;
    private String freePhysicalMemory;
    private int memoryUsage;
    private double cpuUsage;
    private String ipAddress;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you've discovered, you cannot have a string on the y-axis of a line chart.
see the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#data-format) for specifics...

however, we can use object notation to represent the ip address by a number.
then display the address instead of the number.

when loading a cell in google's data table,
we can provide an intrinsic value, such as --> `'127.0.0.1'`

or we can use an object, and provide both the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)
`{v: 0, f: '127.0.0.1'}`

this will cause the chart to use zero for the value, but display the address on the chart.
this solves half of our problem, by loading the data in the data table.

now we must solve the issue of the labels actually displayed on the y-axis.
here, we can use the `ticks` option.
the `ticks` option will accept the same object notation above.
so if we want ip addresses on the y-axis, supply `ticks` as follows...

```
[{v: 0, f: '127.0.0.1'}, {v: 0.1, f: '127.0.0.2'}, {v: 0.2, f: '127.0.0.3'}]
```

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var serverStatuses = [
    {memoryUsage: 0.1, ipAddress: '127.0.0.1'},
    {memoryUsage: 0.3, ipAddress: '127.0.0.2'},
    {memoryUsage: 0.5, ipAddress: '127.0.0.3'},
    {memoryUsage: 0.7, ipAddress: '127.0.0.4'},
    {memoryUsage: 0.9, ipAddress: '127.0.0.5'},
  ];

  var performanceData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  performanceData.addColumn('number', 'Memory Usage');
  performanceData.addColumn('number', 'Server IP');

  var axisTicks = [];
  serverStatuses.forEach(function (row, index) {
    var address = {
      v: index,
      f: row.ipAddress
    };
    axisTicks.push(address);
    performanceData.addRow([
      row.memoryUsage,
      address
    ]);
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(performanceData, {
    vAxis: {
      ticks: axisTicks
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```